# Does JVM support dump heap when some fatal error occurs？

Tags: jvm

I know that we can dump heap for the jvm when oom occurs.

but currently I want to dump it when some fatal error occurs.

Anyone knows how to achieve that.

Comment: what's the exact cause of fatal error ? can you post error msg